# Spark on YARN: Less executor memory than set via spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark, containers, hadoop-yarn, hortonworks-data-platform, executor

I'm using Spark in a YARN cluster (HDP 2.4) with the following settings:

- 1 Masternode

  - 64 GB RAM (48 GB usable)
  - 12 cores (8 cores usable)
- 5 Slavenodes

  - 64 GB RAM (48 GB usable) each
  - 12 cores (8 cores usable) each
- YARN settings

  - memory of all containers (of one host): 48 GB
  - minimum container size = maximum container size = 6 GB
  - vcores in cluster = 40 (5 x 8 cores of workers)
  - minimum #vcores/container = maximum #vcores/container = 1

When I run my spark application with the command `spark-submit --num-executors 10 --executor-cores 1 --executor-memory 5g ...` Spark should give each executor 5 GB of RAM right (I set memory only to 5g due to some overhead memory of ~10%).

But when I had a look in the Spark UI, I saw that each executor only has 3.4 GB of memory, see screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Can someone explain why there's so less memory allocated?

Comment: [Check this out](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#memory-management-overview)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The storage memory column in the UI displays the amount of memory used for execution and RDD storage. By default, this equals (HEAP_SPACE - 300MB) * 75%. The rest of the memory is used for internal metadata, user data structures and other stuffs.

You can control this amount by setting `spark.memory.fraction` (not recommended). See more in [Spark's documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#memory-management)

Comment: Does HEAP_SPACE match the "--executor-memory" value? If so, then the execution memory should be (5 * 1024 - 300) * 0.75 = 3615 MB which equals 3,53 GB. Then there are still > 0.1 GB missing.

Comment: Just tried out: set "spark.memory.fraction" to 0.9, which should then lead to a execution memory of (5 * 1024 - 300) * 0.9 = 4338 MB = 4.24 GB. But in Spark UI it shows 4.0 GB.

Comment: Heap size in Java program is imprecise. When you ask the JVM for a 5g heap using `-Xmx5g`, it doesn't give you a heap of `5 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024` bytes, but a smaller number. Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13988748/205528

Comment: Ok, so let's say the "imprecision-factor" is 3% (middle of 1 - 5%), then the calculation looks the following: (5 * 1024 * 0.97 - 300) * 0.75 = 3500 MB = 3,42 GB. This sounds plausible. Thank you, didn't know about this Java "problem"...