# Apache Spark: cores vs. executors

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, kubernetes, pyspark

Questions related to cores vs executors are asked number of times on SO.

[Apache Spark: The number of cores vs. the number of executors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24622108/apache-spark-the-number-of-cores-vs-the-number-of-executors)

As each case is different, I'm asking similar question again.

I'm running a cpu intensive application with same number of cores with different executors. Below are the observations.

**Resource Manager :** Kubernetes

**Case 1:** Executors - 6, Number of cores for each executor -2, Executor Memory - 3g, Amount of Data processing ~ 10GB, Partitions -36, Job Duration : **75 mins**

**Case 2:** Executors - 4, Number of cores for each executor -3, Executor Memory - 3g, Amount of Data processing ~ 10GB, Partitions -36, Job Duration : **101 mins**

As per the above link anything less than 5 cores per executor is good for IO operations.

In both my cases cores are same(12), however both jobs took different times. Any thoughts?

**Updated**

**Case 3:** Executors - 12, Number of cores for each executor -1, Executor Memory - 3g, Amount of Data processing ~ 10GB, Partitions -36, Job Duration : **81 mins**

Comment: How many nodes are you running on? Is it the same for both cases?

Comment: It's 10 node cluster in both the cases.

Comment: It is not clear to now if num-executors is used or not from looking at various posts and docs, BTW..

Comment: It's is a pure guess without any code. How often have you conducted your runs? What is your data source?

Comment: @cronoik, datasource is gcp, I was trying with multiple cases(trail and error), as of now there are no full fledged runs. Both the rans had one after the other.

Comment: First of all I would conduct several runs to avoid outliniers. I have never worked with gcp, but I assume that your data is avaiable on all your nodes and that therefore 6 executors are faster as 4 executors.

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible solutions, 
First of all not all nodes are born equal, it might be one of the jobs got unlucky and got a slow node.
Seconds if you perform shuffle operations having more nodes but the same computation power will really slow your job. after all in a shuffle operation all of your information will be eventually stored on a single node. having this node with less data before hand and less power will slow the operation.
But I suspect that even without shuffle operations more nodes will be a bit slower, as there is a higher chance of a single node having more work to do from other nodes.

Explanation:

Lets say I have a single node and 10 hour of work and 10 cores, so I know it will take 1 hour
but if I have 2 nodes, with 5 cores each and lets say the dataset was partitioned in a way one node has 5.5 hours of work  and the other 4.5 hours , the job length will be 1.1 hours.

There is always overhead price to pay for distributed computing. so Its usually faster to do work with the same resources on a single machine.

Hope what I tried to say is clear.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you do have 50% more memory to work with (3g*6=18g) while have less locking issues (2 cores/executor instead of 3). Try dynamic allocation with 1core/executor and see what happens

Comment: Updated the stats with 1core/executor, still it took more time than 2 core per executor.